# telerik mvc combobox copy and initialize

Tags: asp.net-mvc, combobox, telerik

I am using a Telerik combobox and using jquery to make a clone of it.

the control is being rendered correctly, however the dropdown is not working I believe due to the fact the javascript has not been initialized on the control.

Is there a way to do this or a better way to make a duplicate of the control?

I may have to resort to making an ajax request but would ideally like to keep it all clientside.

Cheers,

Mark

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After the clone you need to attach the AJAX call to it as follows.

```
var c = $('rowTemplate').clone();
c.find('selectorToGetInputControl').tAutoComplete({ ajax: { "selectUrl": "Your Ajax Call" },filter: 1 });
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer I'm going to assume it works although I changed from cloning the control to doing a partial page load which worked around the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how you attempt to make a client clone of MVC server control using jQuery, I doubt such thing can operate properly. Either use another instance of the combo or go for pure client-side component.

Comment: I dont see why it wouldnt work propertly as long as I make all of the id's unique the control itself isnt particulary complicated and telerik use jquery so it just needs the correct bits of jquery to be run, I was just hoping someone might know which bits as I dont want to have to reverse engineer the telerik code